# Seed for dropout in Tensorflow LSTM - Difference in model(X) and model.predict(X)

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, tf.keras, random-seed, dropout

Outputs for LSTM layer in tensorflow when using `model(X`) and `model.predict(X)` differ when using dropout.

Let's call the output of `model(X)` as **Fwd Pass** and `model.predict(X)` as **Prediction**

For a regular dropout layer, we can specify the `seed` but LSTM layer doesn't have such an argument. I'm guessing this is causing the difference between these **Fwd Pass** and **Prediction**.

In the following code sample, if `dropout=0.4`, these the outputs are different but when `dropout=0.0` they match exactly. This makes me believe that every evaluation is using a different operation level seed.

Is there a way to set that? I've already set the global seed for tensforflow.

Is there something else going on, that I am not aware of?

PS: I want to use dropout during inference, so that is by design.

Code

```
import os
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.initializers import GlorotUniform

SEED = 200
HIDDEN_UNITS = 4
N_OUTPUTS = 1
N_INPUTS = 4
BATCH_SIZE = 4
N_SAMPLES = 4

np.random.seed(SEED)
tf.random.set_seed(SEED)


# Simple LSTM Model
def my_model():
    inputs = x = keras.Input(shape=(N_INPUTS, 1))
    initializer = GlorotUniform(seed=SEED)

    x = layers.LSTM(HIDDEN_UNITS,
                     kernel_initializer=initializer,
                     recurrent_dropout=0.0,
                     dropout=0.4,
                     # return_sequences=True,
                     use_bias=False)(x, training=True)

    output = x
    model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[output])
    return model

# Create Sample Data
# Target Function
def f_x(x):
    y = x[:, 0] + x[:, 1] ** 2 + np.sin(x[:, 2]) + np.sin(x[:, 3] ** 3)
    y = y[:, np.newaxis]
    return y

# Generate random inputs
d = np.linspace(0.1, 1, N_SAMPLES)
X = np.transpose(np.vstack([d*0.25, d*0.5, d*0.75, d]))
X = X[:, :, np.newaxis]
Y = f_x(X)

# PRINT FWD PASS
model = my_model()
n_out = model(X).numpy()
print('FWD PASS:')
print(n_out, '\n')

# PRINT PREDICT OUTPUT
print('PREDICT:')
out = model.predict(X)
print(out)
```

**Output (`dropout=0.4`) - do not match**

```
FWD PASS:
[[ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.0526864  -0.13284351  0.02326298 -0.30357683]
 [ 0.06297918 -0.14084947  0.02214929 -0.44425806]] 

PREDICT:
[[ 0.00975818 -0.029404    0.00678372 -0.03232396]
 [ 0.0347842  -0.0974849   0.01938616 -0.15696262]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.06297918 -0.14084947  0.02214929 -0.44425806]]
```

**Output (`dropout=0.0`) - no dropout, outputs match**

```
FWD PASS:
[[ 0.00593475 -0.01799661  0.00424165 -0.01876264]
 [ 0.02226446 -0.06519517  0.01399653 -0.08595844]
 [ 0.03620889 -0.10084937  0.01987283 -0.1663805 ]
 [ 0.0475584  -0.12453148  0.02269932 -0.2541136 ]] 

PREDICT:
[[ 0.00593475 -0.01799661  0.00424165 -0.01876264]
 [ 0.02226446 -0.06519517  0.01399653 -0.08595844]
 [ 0.03620889 -0.10084937  0.01987283 -0.1663805 ]
 [ 0.0475584  -0.12453148  0.02269932 -0.2541136 ]]
```

Comment: model.predict disables the learning phase (setting it to False) so Dropout is effectively disabled, that is why you get different results.

Comment: for a dropout layer -  `layers.Dropout(rate=DROPOUT_RATE, seed=SEED)(x, training=True)`, argument `training` supersedes model.predict setting so dropout can be enabled. I think dropout for RNN follow the same rules